# Is there a way to prevent the execution of a try block if an exception is executed?

Tags: python

Is there a way to prevent the rest of a try block from executing if an exception is executed?  Say for example I've run out of `ingredient 1`, how do I prevent the rest of the try block from executing once that exception is executed?

```
try:
    #add ingredient 1
    #add ingredient 2
    #add ingredient 3
except MissingIngredient:
    print 'you are missing ingredients'
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything. If exception is thrown in `add ingredient 1` then the other two won't be excuted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens automatically:

```
class MissingIngredient(Exception):
    pass

def add_ingredient(name):
    print 'add_ingredient',name
    raise MissingIngredient

try:
    add_ingredient(1)
    add_ingredient(2)
    add_ingredient(3)
except MissingIngredient:
    print 'you are missing ingredients'
```

The rest of the try block will not be executed if one of its expression raises exception. It will print:

```
add_ingredient 1
you are missing ingredients
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another try/catch block in the original try block.

```
try:
    #add ingredient 1
    #add ingredient 2
    #add ingredient 3
except MissingIngredient:
    try:
         ....
    except MissingIngredient:
         ....

    print 'you are missing ingredients'
```

However, possibly the following structure is better:

```
try:
    #add ingredient 1

    try:
        #add ingredient 2

        try:
            #add ingredient 3

            # Here you can assume ingredients 1, 2 and 3 are available.

        except MissingIngredient:
            # Here you know ingredient 3 is missing

    except MissingIngredient:
        # Here you know ingredient 2 is missing

except MissingIngredient:
    # Here you know ingredient 1 is missing
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. It should immediately pull out of the try block to the except clause; the only way I know of to keep going is some kind of try... except... finally...